# Should I use class method or instance method, and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, model-view-controller

In my Rails app, when creating a business I have a form that has the following field:

```
   <%= check_box_tag(:default_company) %> 
   <%= label_tag(:default_company, "Set Company as Default") %>
```

Essentially when I create a business, if they check this box, I need it to run something like the following code:

```
def set_default_company(company, user)
  exists = DefaultCompany.find(user.id)
  if exists
    exists.update_attributes(company: company)
  else  
    DefaultCompany.create(company: company, user: user)
  end
end
```

While learning, I would usually do that stuff in my controller but i'm trying to follow best practices and use a fat model, skinny controller, so I'm wanting to use logic like this:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])

  if @company.save
    if params[:default_company]
      Company.set_default_company(@company.id, current_user.id,)
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Company was successfully created."
    redirect_to @company
  else
    redirect_to new_company_path
  end
end
```

Here is where I am getting confused on whether to use a class method or an instance method, to call `set_default_company`. They both seem like they would work and I can't see a benefit to one or the other.

In addition to giving me any information as to which method to use, if someone could show me a brief implementation of writing that as a class method vs. instance method it may give me a better understanding as to why.

Here is how I would write them:

```
def self.set_default_company(company, user)
  # Logic here
end

def set_default_company(company, user)
  # Logic here
end
```

Writing them that way I don't see a benefit to either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As their name suggests, instance methods on a model should be used for logic/operations that relate to a specific instance of a user (the one on which the method is called.) So you could think of setting the default company for a user as an instance method on `User`. Class methods are for things which don't operate on an individual instance of a model or for cases where you don't have the instance available to you. e.g. you might have a class method to tidy up your database such as `User.purge_expired_users` which would not apply to an individual user object.

e.g.

```
class User
  def set_default_company(company)
    exists = DefaultCompany.find(self.id)
    if exists
      exists.update_attributes(company: company)
    else  
      DefaultCompany.create(company: company, user: self)
    end
  end
end
```

then your controller method would look like:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])

  if @company.save
    if params[:default_company]
      current_user.set_default_company @company
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Company was successfully created."
    redirect_to @company
  else
    redirect_to new_company_path
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could think of the relationship from the other perspective and put an instance method on `Company` e.g. `company.set_as_default_for(user)`.

Comment: Very good description for class vs. instance, actually really cleared it up for me. You are correct I am going to move this to my user model rather then company, that makes the most sense and reads better. I have one last question. Instead of storing the default company in a table called Default Company which is a joining table of user_id and company_id, should I just have a "default_company" field in the user model? The reason I went with a joining table is because not all users will have a company, in fact most won't have a  company, so I would have blank fields a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I would actually make `set_default_company` an instance method on `User`. A `User` has a default `Company`; why should a `Company` need to what users it is default for?

```
class User
    def set_default_company(company)
        exists = DefaultCompany.find(id)
        if exists
            exists.update_attributes(company: company)
        else  
            DefaultCompany.create(company: company, user: self)
         end
     end
 end
```

Comment: You are correct. I originally was going to do this but for some reason my thinking lead me away from that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I always create a `class method` if the method in question represents information/behavior that is quite generic among all the objects instantiated, different from the `instance methods`, that I use when I believe it's more like a specific action of the instantiated object in question.

But that is my point-of-view.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: do you have a separate table for DefaultCompany? This seems like it should be a boolean flag on the company table.

Next, is there an association between companies and users? If so, it seems the best way to do it would be

In the user model

```
def set_default_company(company)
  self.companies.each do |c|
    c.update_attributes(:default => false)
  end
  company.update_attributes(:default => true)
end
```

Or in the Company model

```
def set_as_default
  update_attributes(:default_company => true)
end
```

Comment: I do have a separate table for DefaultCompany, the thinking that led me away from the boolean is that a user has_many companies through roles, so a user can have potentially many or no companies. So the boolean field doesn't really work in that case, I don't think

Comment: Consider the case where a company has 5 users, if I set the company boolean field to true it would set it for all of the users, correct?

Comment: Forgot to mention it was a companies have many users through roles and users have many companies through roles as well

Comment: if each user can have only one default company, then the default should be a boolean on the roles table

Comment: Hmmm yes that make sense, a user could in theory have a role of "Owner" and "Manager", so it seems to me like i'd have to keep track of both?  Or I guess I would just check for all roles where user a belongs to company x and set all those roles to true, that seems better to you then a joining table?

Comment: what's the purpose of the DefaultCompany table? Is it to say which Company is a user's primary company, and then there is a different concept of the primary role? Or, if a user had a primary role, could you infer the primary company from the primary role? If there is a need to have a different primary company from the company in a primary role, then you would need a different table. However, it seems here that you could do everything with a boolean on the row.

Comment: so, primary company would be `primary_role.company`

Comment: The purpose of the DefaultCompany table is to give a default value when a user has more than one company. This app incorporates a bidding system, and if a user has more then one company attached (aka a role with two companies) then I need to know when they place a bid which company to default the bid as, instead of making them choose every time. So I want to be able to call something like user.default_company

Comment: if so, you could definitely do it with a boolean on role for primary role, and then have a method in the user model user.default_company

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing it this way rather then the Table? I plan on caching it so I don't have to look it up every time, but maybe it's cleaner as well?

Comment: from a data complexity standpoint, it will probably be easier in the future to express the same ideas / have the same data, with one less table